# Is there a program to mine bitcoins in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-recommendation, bitcoin

I do not understand much about mine bitcoins, but I downloaded a program that is like a wallet, but I want to know how I do to mine.
Has a calling GUIminder but is for windows, someone knows one that is for ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use bfgminer

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:unit3/bfgminer
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get install bfgminer
```

More info (spanish)
http://probandoubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/12/bfgminer-una-forma-mas-facil-de-minar.html

Answer (score 9):

Yes. http://bitcoin.org/en/download

However, Bitcoin mining now requires EXTREMELY more sophisticated hardware than it did at the onset of Bitcoin; FPGAs and GPUs have outpaced using a simple CPU for the computation, and since all of the easy computations to get a Bitcoin have been done. there's a curve of decreasing returns to make more. Charles Stross explains it well, if vehemently, [here](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2013/12/why-i-want-bitcoin-to-die-in-a.html).

You may find https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining useful in considering if it is practical for you and whether you will make more cash money than you spend in electricity to run the PC, especially since nowadays it seems to be the outfits which sell Bitcoin mining machines http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2013-11-14/2014-outlook-bitcoin-mining-chips-a-high-tech-arms-race who are making the money http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/11/14/firm_makes_3million_during_bitcoin_gold_rush/ as the previous two links show. It's like the California Gold Rush. Who made the money? The storekeepers who sold mining equipment and supplies to the miners, not the miners themselves.

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident running an application in a Terminal window you should look into CGMiner.

http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/

You would download the built version (cgminer-x.x.x-x86_64-built.tar.bz2) and untar it using `tar -vxjf`.
From a terminal window you pass your mining pool information to the program:

`cgminer -o url -u user -p pass`

But read as much as you can about bitcoin mining before you decide to get serious about.  Check out the bitcoin mining sub-Reddit and www.bitcointalk.org.